# Getting 'get_any' method on the SObject class when building a JAR from Partner WSDL?

Tags: soap-api, java, partner-wsdl

We haven't had to build a new version of the partner wsdl jar for SOAP API work since version 12 and things have changed a bit. I'm trying to work with v43.0, but I'm doing something wrong. I've tried following the quickstart guide, but I can't seem to get a SObject class generated that has the `get_any` method our codebase and examples documents should be there.

All dependency jars are local:

```
java -classpath force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:ST-4.0.8.jar:axis-1.4.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc production.partner.wsdl.xml sf-api-43.partner.jar
```

I understand that axis somehow provides this to the sObject, but I've not uncovered how or what I'm doing wrong here.

Should I be seeing a `get_any` method on the SObject class in the resulting jar? (or anywhere in that jar?)

Comment: What did this method do?

Comment: SObject.get_any() returns an array of MessageElement objects. All the samples that use the Partner WSDL show it being used to iterate over the fields present on the SObject.

Comment: Do you have a link which demonstrates that somewhere? I did a quick search and didn't find anything promising.

Comment: I find samples on other sites, but now that I'm realizing the samples for v43 api don't show field iteration. I wonder if the lack of results from developer.salesforce.com docs is indicating it's been fully removed from the newer versions of the API in favor of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after putting this problem down and returning to it over the holiday. Hope this saves the next person to hit this wall.

**When using Axis 1.4**, as the `get_any` method is no longer provided by the sObject class from the force-wsc project, you must use `getChildren` (defined on the super class of sObject, XmlObject). It will return an Iterator of XmlObjects.

Get the name of a field via `getName().getLocalPart()` on each XmlObject. The value via `getValue()`.

```
public static String toString(SObject sObject) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    buf.append(sObject.getType()).append(" ").append(sObject.getId()).append("\n");

    Iterator<XmlObject> fields = sObject.getChildren();
    while(fields.hasNext()) {
        XmlObject field = fields.next();
        buf.append("\t").append(field.getName().getLocalPart()).append("=").append(field.getValue()).append("\n");
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Note its different with Axis 2.** I did not explore upgrading my Axis.